# Why does error alert not working for getJSON?

Tags: json

I am loading json data as below

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "success") {
        myData= data;
    } else {
        window.alert("Unexpected error happened. Please refresh your browser window to reload the page. Error: " + xhr + status);
    }
});
```

However, I tested this by deleting the json file. And expecting 404 result. HOwever, that didn't show up with alter message. On the console, it does say 404 for the json data. But , why does the alert box not showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getJSON segments calls into success (ie HTTP code 200) and error (ie HTTP non-200).  It doesn't get called when there is a failure (ie non-200).  Therefore, status will always be "success" when its called because when its not this callback isn't called.

You should consider converting to using promises because it's much more flexible.  Use the done() method to register the section of code for when a 200 is received, and the fail() method for when a non-200 is received. try this:

```
$.getJSON('someurl').done( function( data ) {
   myData = data;
}).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("Unexpected error happened. Please refresh your browser window to reload the page. Error: ", textStatus, " ", errorThrown);
});
```

Also consider using console.log instead of alert when writing debugging code.  You can leave console.log() calls in your code where alerts() you have to remember to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

because the callback function of getJSON only works when requesting successfully. 
you should use

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {404: function() {
    alert('page not found');
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to take my code and add some more status code to it test for errors like those?

Comment: you can visit [jQuery API Document](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), find "statusCode", and check it.

Comment: Just so other people are aware this will only work for when 404 is returned.  It won't handle the plethora of other status codes that could be returned like 500, 550, 403, etc.  Also you have converted from using a call that interprets JSON for you to raw ajax call that you will need to configure to handle JSON data for you.  This really doesn't fix the OPs problem and arguably creates more problems to solve.